# AWS Transfer for SFTP, disable multipart upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sftp

I use [AWS Transfer for SFTP](https://aws.amazon.com/sftp/) service and ran into an issue with multipart upload and numerious S3 events triger my Lambda for every uploaded file part. I'd like to disable all of these events and receive only one single event after full file upload. How to achieve it?

**UPDATED**

We have created the following matrix that displays results of our testing file upload through AWS Transfer for SFTP(which in my understanding is a sync between SFTP and S3):

[image]

```
PUT, POST, COPY, Multipart upload completed, All object create events - means AWS S3 events we have tested
Y - means, event was triggered 
N - event was not trigered
```

When we try to upload a little bit larger file(~4MB) we receive 2 notifications with different AWS Request IDs and different s3_object_key: `filename.txt` and `filename.txt.filepart`.

Comment: S3 does not create event notifications for each part of a multipart upload -- only when the upload is complete, so I believe you may have misdiagnosed the nature of the problem as being related to multipart uploads, when the problem is somewhere else.  Enable logging on the bucket.  The value in `event.Records[0].responseElements.['x-amz-request-id']` in the event notification data is unique to each event notification, and will match the `Request ID` (column 6) of a row in the bucket log file, so you can correlate it to a single bucket API request that actually triggered the Lambda invocation.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for your answer. I have updated my question and provided more details. Could you please take a look into this?

Comment: Aha.  The `.filepart` thing is almost certainly something being done by your SFTP client -- S3 multipart uploads don't use extensions like that.  Are you using WinSCP by chance?  Take a look at [this](https://kb.globalscape.com/Knowledgebase/11342/Files-uploaded-using-WinSCP-are-being-moved-with-filepart-extension), for example.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for your answer. You were right! WinSCP is the reason of this behaviour.

Comment: @alexanoid How did you address the issue? I am also getting upload-event for each `.filepart`  When I a file uploads I attached tags on the uploaded file. Also tagging on `.filepart` is not allowed so my trigger code breaks :(

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan it was not an issue of AWS. It was about how WinSCP client uploads the data. It splits the big file to a set of small chunks and upload them separatly. This way they look for S3 as a separate files(what they actually are at this moment) and this why I received such events.

Comment: @alexanoid Yes, I read all comments and understood the reason... I think I should fix my lambda if the file extension is `.filepart` silently skip the file. Thanks